# Is this a right way to use "to no avail"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, sentence

But to not his avail,they didn't pay him any attention.

Comment: But his efforts were to no avail, as they paid him no attention.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the right way to use *to no avail*.

*To no avail* is an adjunct of result in clause structure with a meaning similar to *unsuccessfully*, *with no result*, or *fruitlessly*. It is pretty much a set phrase that does not permit the addition of other elements. The *no* may be swapped out for *little, much* or *what* depending on the degree of success or interrogative use.

Besides this, your sentence is defective in that the main clause is concerned with what *they* did. What you need is a main clause about what *he* did  *to no avail*.

e.g.

*He atttempted to enter the conversation several times to no avail.*

Comment: thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

"Avail" means "help or benefit" and those words can quite effectively be substituted.

> But to not his help, they didn't pay him any attention

Doesn't really make any sense.

It isn't clear what you are trying to say here, but let me interpret a little. You might say (trying to retain your basic sentence structure):

> He yelled, but to no avail, they didn't pay him any attention.

His yelling provided no help or benefit, because they still didn't pay him any attention. However, this isn't a great sentence either since it is an ugly comma splice. So, I'd suggest a better way to say it would be:

> His yelling availed him not since they didn't pay him any attention.

Or even better:

> His yelling was to no avail, because they did not pay him any attention.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now.